# Time Complexity Improvement for Project Euler Solution

Tags: java

This is my solution to the first question in [Project Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Euler).

Could someone please help reduce the time complexity of this working code?

Problem:

If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

```java
public class Sum {
    private static final int n = 1000; 
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1, sum = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            if ((i % 3 == 0) || (i % 5 == 0)) {
                 System.out.println(sum += i);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As stated, the question has a trivial solution: precompute  the sum and emit it in O(1).

Comment: You're probably familiar with the Gauss formula for summing integers from 1..n as `n*(n+1)/2`.  If you have a sequence of n values skip-counting by k, the formula is just `k*n*(n+1)/2`.

Comment: Your O(n) solution is fine for the first problem. Just submit it, then look at the forum there (accessible after submission) for an O(1) approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the formula provided by [phatfingers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1031887).

You can have numbers that are divisible by 15 (3 * 5), so you kinda have to subtract that amount.

Because the formula without `k` works for all natural numbers up to `n`, you multiply the thing by `k`. But this expands your scale by a factor of `k`, so I divided `n` by `k` (automatically being rounded down).

```
public class Sum {
    private static final int n = 15;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = compute(3, n) + compute(5, n) - compute(15, n);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static int compute(int k, int n) {
        n = n / k;
        return k * n * (n + 1) / 2;
    }
}
```

Note:

1. You can declare your variables inside of the for-loop
2. You check i < n (n exclusive) instead of i <= n (n inclusive, which I think you want here). If you don't want this, change `n = n / k` to `n = (n - 1) / k`.